# Casting Interfaces with ILIST

Tags: c#, interface

I have field X of type `ILIST <ITopics>`

I am trying to do this:

```
Object.X= AListOfSometypeThatInheretsITopics;
```

How do I properly cast the list to the Object.X?

Answer (score 8):

This requires [generic variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359(VS.80).aspx), which is unfortunately not possible with `IList<T>` because it expresses a mutable list interface.  Your best bet is to either use a non-generic `IList` or a generic `IEnumerable<T>` (which is amenable to variance as of C# 4) as the field/property type, or convert it by a mechanism such as

```
x = inputList.OfType<ITopics>().ToList();
```

to obtain a list of the appropriate flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
object.x = IList<ITopics>.ofType<ITopics>().ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `IEnumerable<T>` extension method Cast

```
Object.X = yourList.Cast<ITopics>().ToList();
```

Comment: That gives you an IEnumerable<T> not an IList<T>.